# Symfony routing API problems

Tags: php, api, symfony, routes

I am coding an API to improve my personnal PHP skills.
I have a problem with 2 routes :

```
recette.recetteById:
   path: /api/recette/{id}
   controller: App\Controller\RecetteController::recetteById

recette.subRecette:
  path: /api/recette/sub-recette
  controller: App\Controller\RecetteController::subRecette
```

When I go to `/api/recette/sub-recette` it shows me the return of my `recetteById` function instead of `subRecette`, it seems that `/sub-recette` is used as `/{id}`.

My `recetteById` is just a function that returns the id as json, so when I go to `/api/recette/sub-recette` it show `sub-recette`. Why the route doesn't call my `subRecette` function?

What do I have to do to call `subRecette` function when I go `/api/recette/sub-recette`

recetteByID :

```
public function recetteById($id) {
  return $this->json($id);
}
```

Comment: That dot in route names really strikes my eye. Can you try replacing it with `_`?

Comment: i can't it it must be name "sub-recette"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing the question and reading it more closely, I see what the issue is.

The routing works by the principle first match wins. To it, the `sub-recette` looks a lot like a perfectly valid ID.

In order to circumvent this, if your ID is, say, number, you could do:

```
recette.recetteById:
    path: /api/recette/{id}
    requirements: 
        id: '\d+'
    controller: App\Controller\RecetteController::recetteById
```

Another way to achieve this is to put `subRecette` before `recetteById` but this is error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works :), and thanks for the editing too. By the way, what is an "error-prone" if i place `subRecette` before `recetteById`

Comment: You let the order or routes dictate the validity. Inevitably, in some projects, you will make mistake and put some routes in the wrong order, causing an error :)